# Use global variable as parameter in Jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery UI autocomplete to do a search in a database to search for a song. I have a global variable (artist) that I want to pass as a parameter to the autocomplete event.

```
var artist = 0;

// do some stuff to change the variable artist

$(function() {
    $("#track1").autocomplete({
      source: "tracks.php?id="+artist+"",
    });
});
```

The problem is: the function is always called with the initial value (0) even when that value is changed. Is there an easy way to pass the changed global variable to the autocomplete function?

Comment: You could put your  `$("#track1").autocomplete({` into a function of it's own and call it when you have updated the artist.

Comment: You can use the `source: function (request, response)` and make you own request. Since the function runs each time the correct artist value would be available. The docs site is down right now but there are examples of this in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carsten, the problem was indeed solved by moving `$("#track1").autocomplete({`into a function and calling it when the artist was updated.